# CMake options for Interfacing Qt 5.2.1 (MSVC 2012) with OpenCV

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, cmake

I'm trying to make OpenCV 2.4.9 work with Qt 5.2.1 (MSVC 2012). 
My question is that is it necessary to build the OpenCV libraries from scratch to make them work with QT (Since a pre compiled version with VC 11 is already provided). If this is not the case, how should  I build my OpenCV library with CMake? Should I enable the 'WITH_QT' option or not?

I'm working on windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- "is it necessary to build the OpenCV libraries from scratch to make them work with QT" - yes, definitely.
- " Should I enable the 'WITH_QT' option" - yes. (and check the cmake output carefully, if it found/accepted your QT install)

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. 
Just out of curiosity, why can't I skip this step though? Qt is an IDE and the precompiled versions of OpenCV are a third party library that require a VC 11 compiler to run. SO what is missing in this setup so that we are required to build openCV from scratch again?

Comment: the highgui module chooses the wrapper to be used at compile time (look at the highgui src, there's a window_XXX version for each api). since you can't expect QT to be available on any given box, the plain win32ui wrapper is used for the precompiled libs. choosing qt would also mean, that they have to deliver all the qt libs as dependancies as well ..

Comment: @user3079474 Qt is *not* an IDE. It is an application development framework. Qt Creator is an IDE. The reason you want to compile OpenCV is the same reason you want to compile Qt: to have full control over what goes into your shipping product. Without it, you depend on third parties not to have guffawed making the build. It is also very possible to make binary-incompatible builds using the same compiler if differing compiler options were used for each build. So just the fact that the same compiler was used isn't of much help. Your best bet is to ignore precompiled binaries.